# Determining source of a (masked version) maven dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies

I had a situation in my project where two dependencies relied on a different version of a jar. Just showing the dependency tree only showed the newer version and where it was used, so I ended up going through the POM files (I had an idea where it might be) to find the source.

My question: is it possible to get a dependency tree that includes these dependencies that were removed (showing why they were removed). I seem to recall the m2eclipse plugin can do it, but I'd prefer a command line tool (since I'm not using eclipse).

edit:
Specifically, I already tried the dependency tree, including running with full debug output (-X). As far as I could tell, it doesn't show when it's masking these dependencies.

Comment: In m2e Eclipse you can see things like **omitted for conflict with...** which is such an indicator. The maven-dependency-plugin will print out the same in older versions not in the most-up-to-date version (just try 2.1?) of the maven-dependency-plugin and use the tree goal.

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately version 2.1 fails completely because one of the dependencies apparently references a legacy repository and it ends with a `NoRepositoryConnectorException`.

Comment: Checked it you need 2.1 of maven-dependency-plugin will show the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) use the tree goal to look at the tree of dependencies. But it might be a good idea to use Eclipse via m2e plugin for such problems.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, I made it clearer in the question.

Comment: Okay, version 2.1 of the dependency plugin will show it. I guess using m2e is the only really viable solution for my project though.